# What is the best simple way to remove parts and trim a movie file that you just downloaded off your camera?

Tags: video, avi, crop, mpg

i thought i saw this feature in a blog post but i am trying it with quicktime and it seems like it only works in the pro version.

i dont see this feature at all in windows media player.

this seems like a common pattern:

1. download pics and video from digital camera
2. Play video and realize that there are 10 extra seconds at the end or there is a part in the middle that you want to remove.

What is the best simple way to remove parts and trim a movie file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially resort to a simple video editing program supporting clipping or trimming.

Some free options:

- Windows own [Movie Maker](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/moviemaker/getstarted/clips.mspx).
- Pinnacle [VideoSpin](http://www.videospin.com/redesign/default.asp)
- [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/features.html)

Answer (score 1):

I happen to like [Avidemux](http://www.avidemux.org), free and Free.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to answer from A Dwarf:  If you have Windows Movie Maker installed on your computer, then open it, and go to File --> Import into movie collections.  Or just press Ctrl+I.  You will get an Import File dialog, browse to the file you already downloaded to your computer, select it and click on Import.

After this, follow the Movie Maker Link provided by A Dwarf, which explains how to edit the movie.